# Inline view model in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

ChatGPT keeps telling me I can use an "inline ViewModel" in MVC. I've always had the view models in a different namespace, but the idea of an inline view model would be nice as I often like creating view models for use in only one action, and never anywhere else.

Problem is, ChatGPT and I can't seem to get it to work. Can't seem to find the view model.

Mindful of ChatGPT occasionally making stuff up, I tried to google this, and didn't find anything. Is this a real thing?

And then, in the view, what do I put to reference the IVM? In the `@modal ????` directive of the view?

```
public class profiles
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult ShowProfileName()
{
    var viewModel = new ProfileNamesIVM
        {
            id = _context.Profiles.id,
            name = _context.Profiles.name,
        }
}

public class ProfileNamesIVM
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't think define a class into controller is a good choice. Actually it's my first time to know `inline ViewModel`, I search google and find nothing about it. I also ask chat gpt about it, and gpt tell me that An inline ViewModel is typically defined using an anonymous type or a dynamic object., It seems to be different from yours...

Comment: This is closer to how razor pages work. Where the "controller" and view model are the same class, with the actions as methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the full path of the class so that you can use it view
For cleaning, it is better to consider the model or layer folder

Action

```
return View(viewModel);
```

View

```
[ProjectName].[NamespaceControllers].[NameControllers].[ViewName]
```

Example:

```
@model WebAppSetting.Controllers.HomeController.ProfileNamesIVM

<h1>@Model.id</h1>
<h1>@Model.name</h1>
```